# Drop rows from a dataframe based on a list using a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a list of tweets with their id's in a data frame called "tweet_archive". Some of the tweets associated with these id's have been deleted, which is impairing the analysis I would like to perform. I have created a list of the tweets that need to be deleted called "deleted_tweets", and I am trying to delete those rows from the data frame using a for loop, but nothing seems to be working. I have included my code below. I determined that the length of the list "deleted_tweets" is 25, so I was trying to loop through every row of that list and delete tweets from the "tweet_archive" data frame if the tweet_id matched one in the list. However, when I tried this I got the following error

"ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

```
for x in range(0, 24):
if tweet_archive.tweet_id == deleted_tweets[x]:
    tweet_archive = tweet_archive[tweet_archive.tweet_id != x]
```

Comment: You almost certainly should not be using a loop to filter a dataframe. It would be really helpful if you could provide some sample data in code that we can run (i.e. `pd.DataFrame([...], columns=[...])` of say 4 tweets where 2 have missing data. The answer might be as simple as `df.dropna()`

Answer (score 0):

with out using for loop

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5))
>>> df
    0   1   2   3   4
0   0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8   9
2  10  11  12  13  14
3  15  16  17  18  19
4  20  21  22  23  24
>>> df.drop([1,3]) # [1,3] --> delete_list index
    0   1   2   3   4
0   0   1   2   3   4
2  10  11  12  13  14
4  20  21  22  23  24
>>> df = df.drop([1,3])
```